# Docker exec command without the container ID

Tags: docker

How can do something like:

```
docker exec -it 06a0076fb4c0  install-smt
```

But use the name of the container instead

```
docker exec -it container/container  install-smt
```

I am running a build on CI server so I can not manually input the container ID.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: According docs, you can use the container's name or ID: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#examples

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/gfuv5G/Screen_Shot_2017_12_11_at_3_41_14_PM.png

Comment: Well, actually that's not the container's name but the image's. You could have several started containers form the same image

Comment: @Héctor Seems Looks like it's not working. I am new to docker, is there an additional step required?

Comment: When you start a container, you can pass a `--name` argument. That's what you need.

Comment: Tnx. Is that in docker-compose up -d command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160946/discussion-between-hector-and-johnnyshrewd).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by naming the container with `--name`. Note that your command with `container/container` is likely referencing an *image name* and not the container.

```
➜  ~ docker run --name my_nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx
d122acc37d5bc2a5e03bdb836ca7b9c69670de79063db995bfd6f66b9addfcac

➜  ~ docker exec my_nginx hostname
d122acc37d5b
```

Comment: I get an error when I add --name: `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"--name\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`  Without it: `$ docker run -d  content-services 
79b2719fe2ace023148619447e2e4ed41cd82fbff5eed9813a52f1c37bb5d641`. And with it causes the error `docker run -d  content-services --name dcs`

Comment: @radtek - All arguments must be before the image name

Answer (score 13):

Although it won't save any typing, you can do something like this if you want to use the image name instead of giving the container a name:

```
docker run debian
docker exec -it `docker ps -q --filter ancestor=debian` bash
```

This will only work if you're only running one instance of the `debian` image.

It does help if you're constantly amending the image when working on a new `Dockerfile`, and wanting to repeatedly run the same command in each new container to check your changes worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this by setting a container name in the docker-compose file, and run`docker exec -it` with the name form the file.

@Héctor (tnx)

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: Could you post how the docker-compose file looks like?

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me:

This will start the container named `mytapir` and spawn a shell into the docker container:

`docker run -d --name mytapir -it wsmoses/tapir-built:latest bash`

Upon `docker ps` to ensure the docker container is running:

`docker exec -it mytapir /bin/bash`

Will spawned a shell into an existing container named `mytapir`.

And you can stop the container as usual `docker stop mytapir`.

And starting it via `docker start mytapir`, if it is not running.

(check via `docker ps -a`)